# extending spring mvc controller without using adapter pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have one controller which has 4 request mapping and I cannot do changes in this controller. Is it possible to have a class(controller/component) which overrides one of the request mapping methods to have my custom implementation for this request mapping and using the other 3 request mapping methods as is. Is it possible?

Below is a sample code:

```
@Controller
public class Base {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add() throws Exception {
        return "add";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/update")
    public String update() throws Exception {
        return "update";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove")
    public String remove() throws Exception {
        return "remove";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/show")
    public String show() throws Exception {
        return "show";
    }
}


public class ExtendedBase extends Base {
    public String add() throws Exception {
        return "newAdd";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to override just one method from the parent controller and retain the URLs for all the controller methods, you need a way to prevent Spring from mapping URLs to the parent controller since otherwise you will get duplicate URL mappings when you add the child controller.

Assuming your controllers are:

```
package com.theirs.web.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/base")
public class Base {
  @RequestMapping("/add")
  public String add() { ... }

  @RequestMapping("/update")
  public String update() { ... }

  @RequestMapping("/remove")
  public String remove() { ... }

  @RequestMapping("/show")
  public String show() { ... }
}

package com.mine.web.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/base")
public class ExtendedBase extends Base {
  @Override
  @RequestMapping("/add")
  public String add() { ... }
}
```

You could try this in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.theirs.web,com.mine.web">
  <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.theirs\.web\.controller\.Base" />
</context:component-scan>
```

This will exclude the parent controller class from being managed by Spring while allowing the child class to be managed by Spring.  Thus, there will be only one class mapped to `/base` and its child URLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. This came to my rescue :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only in case if you provide different mapping for the child controller. Otherwise Spring will complain about ambiguous mapping (as you will have two conrollers with the same mapping).

The solution would be to have different mapping for your child controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/child")
public class ExtendedBase extends Base {
    public String add() throws Exception {
        return "newAdd";
    }
}
```

Note here, that you should annotate child class with `@Controller`, otherwise it wouldn't recognize it.

So in this case, you can access your `add()` via both - child and parent controllers. e.g.

- `/add` - will result calling the `Base.add()`
- `/show` - will result calling the `Base.show()`
- `/child/add` - will result calling the `ExtendedBase.add()`
- `/child/show` - will result calling the `Base.show()`

Comment: well in a situation where I can change request mapping your solution would have been perfect. But I cannot change the request mapping. I only want to change the logic inside add method.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way :)